# Rails http caching trying to write to tmp/cache. why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

My understanding was that to use http caching in Rails 3, all I had to do was add something like this to the action

```
expires_in(10.seconds, :public => true)
```

but when I do this, it tries to write to tmp/cache in addition to performing http caching in the browser (same user request for that action doesn't ever hit the server, as expected)

Why is this? How do I stop Rails from writing to the cache directory for http caching?

PS: I'm using nginx+passenger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things that writes to /tmp/cache is [Rack::Cache::FileStore](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-filestore) that is configurable via config.cache_store; It's a rails3 native proxy-cache;
if you want to disable it:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache =  nil
```

Comment: Interesting. Why doesn't it write to tmp/cache in the first place in http caching though?

Comment: @concept47, sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say why **does** it write to tmp/cache at all?

Comment: @concept47, to response be provided with your middleware before the request actually reaches the server

Comment: I thought that was the point of http caching though, that the 2nd request never actually even hits the server?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to not use the :public => true setting in expires_in. It appears that this setting is the reason why Rack::Cache writes the response to cache. If you set it to private => true (the default), this doesn't happen